# How to access HTML components using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

How to access the `HTML` control using `vb.net` and get it's attribute  ?

### edit

I mean if I have `DIV` in tha page, I want to access it using `vb.net` code

### edit 2

if I have in `aspx` page

```
<div id="div2">

</div>
```

I want to access this Div using vb.net code and modify its properties using the code

Comment: Please post your code and markup

Comment: You should describe your requirement and environment better. What are you trying to achieve and what specific question do you have, what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you are using asp.net webforms , you can do this : <div id="myDiv" runat="server >  . . and in your aspx.cs file you can access that div : myDiv.visible=  true .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `<div id="div2" runat="server">` then you can access it in your code behind by using name of the element.